# What is the story of Lakshmi getting curse to have a elephant head?

Tags: scripture, lakshmi

Going through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinayaki) Wikipedia article, I saw about Lakshmi getting a curse to have an elephant head. I never heard this before and Wikipedia is not always reliable. So wanted to know the exact story from scriptures.

Comment: Interesting subject, though never heard of before :-)

Comment: I looked it up and think this is just folkore and not in scriptures. Like the battle between Hanuman and Ram which was made up.

Comment: @Wikash_ that can be an answer too but I will love if you can add that folk tale details/origin etc